# How can I fix this "syntax error or access violation" error?

Tags: 7, database

I am using the following code, but it throws an error.

```php
$query = db_select('sdk_country', 'f');
$query->fields('f', array('id','group'));
$query->condition(array(
  'f.status', 1, '=',
  'f.country_value', 'Afghanistan', '=',
));
$result = $query->execute();
```

The error I get is the following.

> Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `FROM sdk_country f WHERE (Array IS NULL )` at line 1: `SELECT FROM {sdk_country} f WHERE (Array IS NULL ) ; Array ( )` in retreiveEMEAList() (line 458 of C:\Repository\code\beta\sites\all\modules\nhdp_register\nhdp_register.module).

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

[`condition()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3Acondition/7) doesn't take an array as argument.

You need to replace `$query->condition(array('f.status', 1, '=', 'f.country_value', 'Afghanistan', '='));` with the following lines.

```php
// The third argument isn't necessary as `=` is the dafault operator, in this case.
$query->condition('f.status', 1);
$query->condition('f.country_value', 'Afghanistan');
```

The query is using the value of the `status` field, but that isn't added to the list of fields passed to `$query->fields()`.
`group` is a reserved word in MySQL 5.5; it cannot be used as identifier for a table field.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response... I still get the same error. Can you provide the code please.